# For loop issue with undefined return

Tags: for-loop, return-value

the trueDiscount variable returns as undefined. I have no idea why, been trying to fix this for hours. If anyone could help it would be appreciated.

Javascript:

```js
var userQ1 = 11;
var quantity = [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000];
var discount = [.05, .07, .1, .12, .15, .2];
var trueDiscount = calculateDiscount();

function calculateDiscount(userQ1, quantity, discount){
    for (var i=5; i>=0; i--){
        if (userQ1 >= quantity[i]){
            return discount[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you didn't pass the parameters to `calculateDiscount()` in `line 4`
For me, this code is working fine, after passing arguments. with output 0.05

```
var trueDiscount = calculateDiscount(userQ1, quantity, discount);

console.log(trueDiscount)
```

Comment: thank you so much that was the problem!

Comment: Great solve. This should be posted as an answer (rather than a comment) and accepted. @T.M15

Comment: @MattStyles yaa..ok (haha xd)

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the patameters in function in line 4:

```js
var userQ1 = 11;
var quantity = [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000];
var discount = [.05, .07, .1, .12, .15, .2];
var trueDiscount = calculateDiscount(userQ1, quantity, discount);

function calculateDiscount(userQ1, quantity, discount){
    for (var i=5; i>=0; i--){
        if (userQ1 >= quantity[i]){
            return discount[i];
        }
    }
}

console.log(trueDiscount)
```